# shell script match data from another text file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

i have a shell script

```
#/bin/bash
var1=`cat log.json | grep "accountnumber" | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
echo $var
```

output of shell script is :-

```
23466
283483
324932
87374
```

I want match the above number which is already store in another file (below is the file format ) and print its value .

```
23466=account-1
283483=account-2
324932=account-3
87374=account-4
127632=account-5
1324237=account-6
73642=account-7
324993284=account-8
.
.
4543454=account-200
```

exapected output

```
account-1
account-2
account-3
account-4
```

Comment: Why is your file named with a `.json` extension if its format isn't actually JSON?

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 1):

a Compact one line solution can be:

```
join -t "="  <(sort bf) <(sort fa) | cut -d '=' -f 2
```

here **fa** is a file containing out-put of your bash script and **bf** is the file that has **23466=account-1** format

the output is:

```
account-1
account-2
account-3
account-4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for var1 in $(awk -F ' ' '/accountnumber/{print $1}' log.json)
do
  awk -F= '$1=="'"$var1"'"{print $2}' anotherfile
done
```

For a moment there was another answer that *almost* worked that I think is much slicker than what I wrote. Probably faster / more efficient on large files too. Here it is fixed.

```
awk -F ' ' '/accountnumber/{print $1}' log.json \
| sort -n \
| join -t= - accountfile \
| cut -d= -f2
```